# Is there any Blackberry Twitter SDK[Java] which takes care of OAuth

Tags: java, blackberry, twitter, java-me, twitter-oauth

I am developing a small blackberry app which aggregates all celebrity tweets.... For now i am successfully able get all tweets by pinging the public twitter timeline API by passing the username, for example

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=arrahman

I need to have a functionality in app, which enables the user to retweet the celebrity tweet. In order to post to user's timeline twitter needs to authenticate the user.

I am looking for some Blackberry SDK which returns me a token when username and password is passed. so that i can preserve the token in device and reuse the same for subsequent retweets... how do i do that in my blackberry app? Is there any SDK readily available?

If SDKs are available , how to use it, where should i pass username and password parameter? where and how should i save the token? please help.

Comment: have a look to this forum answer:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Is-there-any-jars-for-Twitter-SDk/m-p/1361425#M178093

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at https://github.com/fireeagle/j2me-oauth. I have used it for Oauth on J2ME before and it was pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Also check j2me twitter API here:
http://j2megroup.blogspot.com/2010/08/twitter-api-me-14-new-release.html
and here
http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/pages/Home

they are for blackberry too.